# paster db init -c XXXX/development.ini not working for CKAN-command 'db' not know

Tags: ckan

I am a first time user of CKAN and python, most of my development in `.NET`

I am setting up CKAN for the first time on a Windows 7 computer.  I am trying to run the line:

```
paster db init -c [FOLDER NAME]\development.ini
```

But I keep getting the error Comman `db` not know

I have looked at:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/943-writing-extensions-tutorial/paster.html

I also tried:

```
c:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe --no-site-packages [FOLDER NAME]\ckanext\datastore
```

this did not work

Is there a alternative way to set up the database?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either be in your CKAN source code directory when you run the paster command (`/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan` by default) or you need to do `paster --plugin=ckan ...`. Also make sure your CKAN virtual environment is activated when you run the command. See the note at the top of [CKAN's command line interface docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/paster.html).

The link you gave to the docs is to a very old version of the docs by the way, start at http://docs.ckan.org/ to get the latest.

I don't think anyone has got CKAN working on Windows before, there are known issues I believe, good luck. You might want to consider booting an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine (e.g. with VirtualBox or Vagrant) on your Windows machine, and installing CKAN in that. You will have a *much* easier time if you do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get CKAN 1.8 running on Windows with the help of this page:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-Install-CKAN-1.8-on-Windows
I found the docs sometimes a bit confusing - e.g. the file development.ini contains the configuration of your CKAN installation but it's sometimes also referred to as std.ini ... good luck indeed!